# scraping all comments under an instagram post with python

Tags: python, selenium, comments, instagram, spyder

i get the code from youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fNyKKeiv_0

there's the code starting:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import datetime
import insta_cred as cred

def get_comments():
    
    rettxt = []
    try:
        scroll = True
        count = 0
        while scroll and count < 15 : #scrolling
```

when i'm running this code "import insta_cred as cred", i get error from my console:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'insta_cred'
```

how i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You must install the package to be able to use it. Luckily, Python provides this with the `pip3` utility. If you know the package to be installed (some form of instagram bot), you can run `pip3 install <name of package>` to install it on your machine.

Comment: yes i do, when i install "pip3 install insta_cred" but nothing module for "insta_cred"

Comment: A quick Google search reveals no package named `insta_cred`; Is this part of the university course this is for? If you have access to the code for that package, you need to run `pip3 install .` (note the `.`) in that directory. Otherwise, there seem to be a lot of packages in the Python Package Index for this kind of thing, and you could use those instead (you'll have to read the docs for those though)

Comment: i'm using  `.`  but still not working `pip3 install .insta_cred`  .  this not my university course but i want to learn for my self. thank you so much :)

Comment: If you don't have access to the Python code for `insta_cred`, it won't work. You must have that code, go to the file it is saved in and run `pip3 install .`. I think this code is from the Uni course. Instead, maybe try and use this guide https://realpython.com/instagram-bot-python-instapy/